# Add more elements to javaScript array inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation that I need to add certain elements to a multidimensional array based on a condition. Which means, types of the elements will be based on the condition.

```
if(type == 'text-box'){
     var title = jQuery("#textbox-title-"+id).val();
     var desc = jQuery("#textbox-desc-"+id).val();
     eleDetails[id]['content'] = {title:title, content:desc};
}
else if(type == 'image-box'){
     var title = jQuery("#imagebox-title-"+id).val();
     var imgurl = jQuery("#imagebox-url-"+id).val();
     var desc = jQuery("#imagebox-desc-"+id).val();
     eleDetails[id]['content'] = {title:title, imgurl:imgurl, content:desc};
}
```

So, what's the way of doing this ?

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing seems to work?" Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok I updated the question. I think now the question is OK

Comment: If everything else in your code is working as it should, the way of doing that is the way that you are doing it, considering that eleDetails should be an object, not an array. But obviously something's wrong. Have you checked the error console? What output do you get if you log eleDetails once the code has run? I think you may need to read @EdCottrell 's link again

Comment: Does `eleDetails[i]` exist before you try to set its `content` property? By the way, this is not a "multidimensional array". It seems to be an array of objects, or an object containing other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere:

```
 var eleDetails = {};
```

and in your loop:

```
 var title = jQuery("#textbox-title-"+id).val();
 var desc = jQuery("#textbox-desc-"+id).val();

 // check if eleDetails[id] already exists
 if (!eleDetails[id]) {eleDetails[id] = {};}

 if(type == 'text-box'){
     eleDetails[id]['content'] = {title:title, content:desc};
 }
 else if(type == 'image-box'){
     var imgurl = jQuery("#imagebox-url-"+id).val();
     eleDetails[id]['content'] = {title:title, imgurl:imgurl, content:desc};
 }
```

Comment: `eleDetails` is clearly array of array in his code, not an Object.

Comment: maybe, that's not the most important part of my code